# Landscape Orientation not working when Storyboard iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app I am creating using Storyboards and I only want to support Landscape mode and I have done the follow:

1. Under my Target > Summary I have selected only Landscape Left and Landscape Right for Supported Interface Orientations
2. In my Storyboard I have set all of my ViewControllers to use the following Simulated Metrics- **Size**: iPad Full Screen  **Orientation**: Landscape

Yet on the simulator the iPad will be in Landscape but the view will be in Portrait, same on the iPad BUT only for devices with iOS < 6

Why is this happening?  What am I missing here?

Comment: Hii, you found any solution ? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just copy this code in your app delegate

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    //just write yout desired orientations here
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the info.plist under Supported interface orientations (iPad)...Move the landscape orientation to the top of the list. Your problem will be solved. Worked for me